# How to identify which object is going to be swipe in multiple objects in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I need some help to swipe object or we can say move object on which i have touched.

I have created code in which i'm able to drag only one button.
Suppose i touched on first button it should be active for swipe.

Here is my screen show.
I want to create code for every button for dragging that button on Swipe.

Here is my buttons

[image]

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class SwipeJump : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Vector2 startTouchPosition, endTouchPosition;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float jumpForce = 700f;
    private bool jumpAllowed = false;

    float deltaX, deltaY;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start () 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

        #region newcode
        PhysicsMaterial2D mat = new PhysicsMaterial2D();
        //mat.bounciness = 0.75f;
        //mat.friction = 0.4f;
        GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().sharedMaterial = mat;
        #endregion
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update () 
    {
        //SwipeCheck ();        
        #region newcode
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                    {
                        deltaX = touchPos.x - transform.position.x;
                        deltaY = touchPos.y - transform.position.y;
                        jumpAllowed = true;
                        rb.freezeRotation = true;
                        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
                        rb.gravityScale = 0;
                        GetComponent<Collider2D>().sharedMaterial = null;
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos) && jumpAllowed)
                    {
                        rb.MovePosition(new Vector2(touchPos.x - deltaX, touchPos.y - deltaY));
                    }
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    jumpAllowed = false;
                    rb.freezeRotation = false;
                    rb.gravityScale = 2;
                    PhysicsMaterial2D mat = new PhysicsMaterial2D();
                    //mat.bounciness = 0.75f;
                    //mat.friction = 0.4f;
                    GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().sharedMaterial = mat;
                    break;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you should store the reference of `GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>()` in `Start` and re-use it

Comment: still i'm getting name of my all three object, i just want to gent the name of that object which is swiped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Drag and throw object forcefully in Unity2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744619/how-to-drag-and-throw-object-forcefully-in-unity2d)