# How to Drag and throw object forcefully in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity 2D i want to drag & throw my game object forcefully. basically i have three game object and when i drag anyone off then to upward i should be throw forcefully on that direction.

can anyone tell me how to do it?

i have tried this code but when i'm going to click to drag my game object then it throws directly without dragging it.

here is my code

```c#
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private float jumpForce = 700f;
private bool jumpAllowed = false;

float deltaX, deltaY;

string button_name = "";

// Use this for initialization
private void Start () 
{
    Debug.Log("Started");
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    PhysicsMaterial2D mat = new PhysicsMaterial2D();
    mat.bounciness = 0.75f;
    mat.friction = 0.4f;
    GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().sharedMaterial = mat;
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update () 
{
    Debug.Log("Update");

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                {
                    deltaX = touchPos.x - transform.position.x;
                    deltaY = touchPos.y - transform.position.y;
                    jumpAllowed = true;
                    rb.freezeRotation = true;
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
                    rb.gravityScale = 0;
                    GetComponent<Collider2D>().sharedMaterial = null;
                }
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos) && jumpAllowed)
                {
                    rb.MovePosition(new Vector2(touchPos.x - deltaX, touchPos.y - deltaY));
                }
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                jumpAllowed = false;
                rb.freezeRotation = false;
                rb.gravityScale = 2;
                PhysicsMaterial2D mat = new PhysicsMaterial2D();
                mat.bounciness = 0.75f;
                mat.friction = 0.4f;
                GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().sharedMaterial = mat;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess you need to have a point which is the 'drag distance' behind the touch point enabled when the user first touches the screen. When the user is touching that point the object is thrown.

Comment: On touch begin you save the position of the touch to some private field. On touch end you substract that saved position from the new position and get a vector that represents the total movement of your finger. Now you can use that to apply force to a rigidbody (probably requires some scaling). Alternatively you could add up the delta movement each frame and use that.

Comment: thank you for reply. can any one give me some small code snippet to understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's one mistake

```
rb.MovePosition(new Vector2(touchPos.x - deltaX, touchPos.y - deltaY));
```

should be

```
rb.MovePosition(new Vector2(touchPos.x + deltaX, touchPos.y + deltaY));
```

There's also another issue, `MovePosition` doesn't affect the object velocity at all. If you stop using `MovePosition`, the object will just fall without keeping any energy from the previous movement.

You could simply store the previous position every movement, and do this on `TouchPhase.Ended`:

```
rb.velocity = (rb.position - prevPosition) / Time.deltaTime;
```

Simply put, this calculates the velocity that was required to accomplish the last movement, and apply it to the rigidbody.